# JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK however path is set correctly

Tags: java, jenkins

Yup, this que is answered n number of times.
I have tried all the soln but it is not helping

Build Failed on Jenkins with the following error

com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "D:\Program Files\Java"

My ENV Variables are follows:
%JAVA_HOME%=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;
path=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;

JENKINS systemInfo, under Environment Variables:
%JAVA_HOME% D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;

I have tried every option possible, just couldn't fix a very simple, and basic problem urghhhh :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need, from looking at the values in your question.

```
Variable = JAVA_HOME
Value = D:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_51\
```

Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Enviromental Variables > New
and add the above. (Delete any prexisting and give it a shot)

Then echo %JAVA_HOME% on cmd.

Comment: echo prints the D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;
I have tried with all combinations possible, just can't figure the issue

Comment: As it should, I assume your attempting to compile? Try it now.

Comment: Yup, restarted the jenkins, tried again and it got failed

Comment: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_51\ definitely points to your correct version you have?

Comment: I think ';' splits separate values. But I think because you had the last '\' missing made it fail. Why not try adding '\;' at the end, it should work and answer the question :)

Comment: Nope, that is failing.